# Regarding to the R and Github

Tags: r, github

I tried to create Github repository through entering the following command in the R console:

```
devtools::use_github("https://github.com/SimonFans/RP")
```

But it gives such kind of error:

> Error in gh::gh("POST /user/repos", name = pkg$Package, description = gsub("\n",  :
>     GitHub API error (401): 401 Unauthorized
>     Bad credentials

Does anyone knows how to solve that?

Comment: This is very well described in the documentation. You need to get a token and link to that. Read and reread `?use_github` until you understand every word.

Answer (score 2):

If you execute this command, a new GitHub repo will be created via the GitHub API, therefore you must provide a GitHub
personal access token (PAT) via the argument auth_token, which defaults to the value of the
GITHUB_PAT environment variable. Obtain a PAT from https://github.com/settings/tokens.
The "repo" scope is required which is one of the default scopes for a new PAT.

You don't have this variable set therefore you need to specify it explicitly in your call to function use_github.